# Stuck in my factoring program which is confusing

Tags: python-2.7

I had this program which I have been having a hard time with.
It is a program to find a factor and I am stuck on the edge

I wanted the program to find factors and after it finds a factor it will show a button which says "try again?" --  with the choice of yes or no
and make it find a factor again

```
def print_factors(x):
    print(" The factors of ",x," are: ")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
     if x % i == 0:
        print(i)


try:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print_factors(num)
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.");

while True:
    if input("Try Again? (Yes/No)").strip().upper() == 'No':
     break
```

I don't know how to make the yes and no command work and how to make it find factors and i'm stuck

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\Desktop\factor1.py", line 15, in <module>
    if input("Try Again? (Yes/No)").strip().upper() == 'No':
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Yes' is not defined
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\Desktop\factor1.py", line 9, in <module>
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
Happened to me when i typed in a special character or an alphabet how do i fix this too?

Comment: You have several problems with the posted code, but they aren't causing the error. You are converting the second input to `.upper()` it will never match `'No'` (it is in mixed case). The user is stuck in the while loop, where even though you've asked them to try again, they get no opportunity to re-input a number. More stylistic than functional, but still best practices -- you haven't indented `break` correctly. Use the same number of spaces for each indention level when writing python. The actual error you are receiving is probably due to your text editor. What are you using?

Comment: i'm using python 2.7